# Is there any numerical representation in which each rational has only one representation?

Tags: rational-numbers, decimal-expansion, number-systems

In positional representations, there are always some rational numbers which have multiple representations. For example, in base 10, 1 can be written as 1 or as $0.\overline{9}$. Do there exist any numerical representations in which all rationals have exactly one representation?

Comment: Prime factorization of a number, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Does that hold for all rationals, or just for integers? In other words, is there some non-integer analogue to prime factorization?

Comment: I've written an answer.  I'd be interested in knowing if someone has a more in-depth, analytical explanation.

Comment: Ah cool thanks! I'll wait a bit to see if anybody answers, but if not, yours certainly qualifies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of arithmetic states that every natural number greater than $1$ can be written as a unique product of powers of prime numbers.  Extending this to the rationals simply requires us to allow the negative powers of prime factors.  For example, $$60=2^2\times3\times5$$ and $$\frac{64}{375}=2^6\times 3^{-1}\times5^{-3}.$$

We know that these are unique due to the monotone nature of exponentials.

Answer (score 1):

You can express rational numbers uniquely by terminating continued fractions. Every rational number can be expressed as a finite sequence of integers $[a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n]$ containing at least one term, where $a_i \in \Bbb{Z}$ for $i \ge 0$, and $a_i > 0$ for $i > 0$. We associate $[a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n]$ with

$$\huge{ a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2 + \frac{1}{\ddots_{a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{a_n}}}}}}.$$

The way you convert a rational number to its unique continued fraction is you let $a_0$ be the floor function of the given rational. Subtract $a_0$ from this number, leaving you the fractional part, a number in $[0, 1)$. If the number is $0$, then stop. If the number is positive, then compute its reciprocal to obtain a number greater than $1$. You then start over, letting $a_1$ be the floor of this new number, etc.

As an example, consider $\frac{67}{21}$. The floor of this number is $3$, so we subtract $\frac{67}{21} - 3 = \frac{4}{21}$. We reciprocate this fractional part, which produces $\frac{21}{4}$. We let $a_1$ be the integer part of this number, i.e. $5$, leaving us a fractional part $\frac{1}{4}$. Reciprocating this gives us $4$, which has an integer part of $4$ (so $a_2 = 4$), and a fractional part of $0$, telling us to stop. So, $\frac{67}{21}$ is represented by $[3, 5, 4]$, i.e.
$$\frac{67}{21} = 3 + \frac{1}{5 + \frac{1}{4}}.$$
Note that the denominator of the fraction under consideration is always strictly decreasing, since the fractional part is always less than $1$, so the process will terminate for any rational number.